# POST request updating page in ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, post

I'm trying to make something like a chat with messages from users to Telegram Bot that are storing in DB. On click to chat button request response it's html that the insterted into div. This html code has  SendMessage button that  sends POST request. 
The problem is that POST request sends message but after updating my page the inserted html are dissapears. Url looks like this

> localhost/?

Controller code :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private TelegramBotContext db;
    public HomeController(TelegramBotContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        db.UsersMessage.Load();
        db.Users.Load();
        db.Chats.Load();
        return View(await db.Users.ToListAsync());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Chat(int chId)
    {
        db.UsersMessage.Load();
        db.Users.Load();
        db.Chats.Load();

        var users = await db.Users.ToListAsync();
        var user = users.Where(c => c.Id == chId).FirstOrDefault();
        return PartialView(user);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task SendMessage(string message, int id)
    {
        var bot = BotF.Bot.GetInstance();
        await bot.SendMessage(id, message);

    }
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

JS code :

```
const getChatById = id =>{
let chats = document.querySelectorAll('.chat');
for(chat of chats){
    let attr = chat.getAttribute("ChatId");
    if(attr === id) return chat;
}
}

 const instertChat = chat => document.querySelector("#pDiv").innerHTML = chat;

const ajaxGetChat = chatId => {

sendRequest('Home/Chat' , {chId : chatId} , data => {
    console.log(data);
    instertChat(data);
    const sendButton = document.querySelector('.message_btn');

    sendButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const inputValue = document.querySelector('.sendInput').value;

    sendRequest('Home/SendMessage', {message : inputValue , id : chatId}, data => {
    console.log(data);
    instertChat(data);
      })
  })
})
}



chatButtons.forEach(el=>{
   el.addEventListener("click",() =>{
    let chatId = el.getAttribute("ChatId");
    ajaxGetChat(chatId);
   })
})
```

Requester :

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

const sendRequest = (controller, data, func) => {
xhr.open('POST', controller, true);
console.log(data);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

const dataForSend = toUrlEncoded(data);
xhr.send(dataForSend);
if(func != null){
    xhr.onload = () =>{
        func(xhr.response);
    }
}

}

 const toUrlEncoded = obj => Object.keys(obj).map(k => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + 
 encodeURIComponent(obj[k])).join('&');
```

Index.cshtml :

```
@model IEnumerable<TelegramBotControlMVC.DbContextF.Users>
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="container-fluid main_chat">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 dialogs">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <div class="chat_button" chatId="@item.ChatId">
                <p><b>@item.FirstName</b></p>
                <p>@item.Id</p>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 user_dialog">
            <div id="pDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Chat.cshtml :

```
@model TelegramBotControlMVC.DbContextF.Users
@*
For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? 
LinkID=397860
*@
<div>
        <div class="chat" chatId="@Model.ChatId">
            <div class="chat_instance">
                @foreach (var message in Model.UsersMessage)
                {
                    @if (message.UserId == 1)
                    {
                        <div class="bot_message">
                            <p><b>BOT</b></p>
                            <p>@message.MessageText @message.MessageTime</p>
                        </div>

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="user_message">
                            <p><b>@Model.FirstName</b></p>
                            <p>@message.MessageText @message.MessageTime</p>
                        </div>

                    }

                }
            </div>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 sendInput" ChatId="@Model.Id" 
   placeholder="Message">

                <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 message_btn" 
    ChatId="@Model.Id">Отправить</button>
            </form>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think inside your sendButton event handler you should call [event.preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). Now it's using the form button to call the root after your request and you get two calls to your controller for each button click.

Comment: @JessedeWit ty, now it works fine)